# How do I sync up my iPhone with my Google Calendar?

Tags: iphone, google-calendar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I sync my Google calendar with my iPhone?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/55815/how-do-i-sync-my-google-calendar-with-my-iphone)

So I want to be able to add appointments/events/tasks on either and have those changes reflected on both.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should really use [Google Sync for iPhone](http://www.google.com/support/mobile/bin/answer.py?answer=138740&topic=14252) to have all the benefits of Calendars (and even Mail if you need it).

Comment: The Exchange (Google Sync) mail support is a little lacking. I continue using IMAP for mail, and use Exchange for contacts and calendars. Works great!

Comment: Nice, this one looks like it just works!

Comment: @NReilingh why you think is lacking for mail?

Comment: @gsharp I believe there are issues with syncing saved drafts. Google has this information posted in "known limitations." http://www.google.com/support/mobile/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139635

Comment: I find it _curious_ that an iOS feature is called "Google Sync" - it's baked into the OS using a combination of Exchange ActiveSync technology and plain old CalDAV for the rest.

Answer (score 2):

**In iCal, add a new CalDAV account.**

Description: Google:you@gmail.com

Username: you@gmail.com

Password: yourpass

**SERVER SETTINGS**

Server Address: www.google.com

Server Path: /calendar/dav/you@gmail.com/user/

Port: Auto

Use SSL: CHecked

Make sure you have sync enabled in iTunes.

Comment: To make a new CalDAV account go to ICAL > Preferences > Accounts and click the plus "+" button.