# How do I sync my Google calendar with my iPhone?

Tags: data-synchronization, iphone, google, calendar

So I have set up my calendar on Google. I am trying to get it to sync those changes to my calendar application on my iPhone 4S. I currently have under "Settings > Mail, Contacts, Calendars" the following accounts:

- iCloud (Contacts, Calendars and 5 more..)
- Exchange (Mail, Calendars, Reminders)
- Gmail (Calendars, Notes)

Fetch New Data is set to Push/Every 15 minutes. What am I not doing right? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A quick search led me to this step-by-step guide to sync Google Calendar with iPhone.

http://support.google.com/mobile/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=138740

Comment: Tried this guide sorry I didn't put that in the question ;/.  Perhaps I need to undo my GMAIL account calendar sync and have only this one.  I'll see if that works and post back the results thanks!

Comment: Can you put a digest of the steps to do this in your answer? As it is, your answer is only a link and links do rot, at which point your answer would be useless.

Answer (score 1):

Very simple way to do this:

1. Plug your phone into your computer
2. Launch iTunes
3. Click on the info tab then check "Sync Contacts" and "Sync Google Contacts"
4. Check "Sync Calendars" and select "All Calendars"
5. Go to https://www.google.com/calendar/iphoneselect and make sure you have selected that you want to sync this calendar.

You should now be done, in 15 minutes time everything should sync up nicely.

Comment: Wow how did you find https://www.google.com/calendar/iphoneselect? That's not in the settings anywhere. The iPhone already lets you select Calendars. Why does Google make you select calendars to synch also?